# Matrices multiplification

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions

I have to multiplty 2 matrices in Mathematica, but I have no idea how to force simplification. 
I create matrices by A={{a,1,b,},... and multiply using C=Dot=[A,B]//MatrixForm

My problem is that Mathematica gives output like A*B, but it's not simplified and calculated.

Comment: Please provide code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: A={{1,a,0,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1}}//MatrixForm

B={{1,1,1,1},{0,1,0,a},{a,b,c,d},{0,0,0,1}}//MatrixForm

C=Dot[A,B] //MatrixForm

Comment: You should write `(A = ...) // MatrixForm`, see linked topic and let me know if you disagree with closing.

Comment: Thank you! It worked :) I spend 3h trying to figure it out. The funny thing is that I had the same problem in Maple(working on the same exercise), but obviously the solusion was different.